# No cross-app drag and drop functionality in Juno

Tags: release-juno

I cannot drag and drop a file from Pantheon to Chrome.

Works within Pantheon but when switching the apps, only the drag mouse symbol remains while the actual drop functionality never works.

Comment: Is Desktop Folder installed on your system?

Comment: @a-tokarev yes. Does that have to do anything with this issue?

Comment: I remember experiencing similar drag-and-drop issues before installing DF. As you already have installed DF, then it must be something else.